# Delete method throwing up missing ID error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I created a simple delete method, trying to learn the restful routes stuff.  Anyway, so if I delete the post on the show page it works fine, but if I go back to the index page, click on the post and then hit delete, it throws up a missing ID error, but it still deletes it anyway.  Very confused :D

I'll post more code if I need to, but I'm 95% sure the problem is right here.  Also, I couldn't figure out the restful route redirect.

I had this:

```
redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
```

And that obviously wasn't right, so I just went back to the way I learned first:

```
def destroy
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    @blog.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that after deleting the blog you want to go back to the list of blogs.

You can redirect to the index path with
`redirect_to blogs_path`

You could code your `destroy` method like:

```
def destroy
  begin
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.destroy
      redirect_to blogs_path, notice: 'Blog destroyed.'
    else
      redirect_to blog_path(@blog), alert: "Blog could not be destroyed."
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to blogs_path, alert: "Blog with id '#{params[:id]}' not found"
  end
end
```